# How should I handle multiple markets while writing UI Automation with Espresso?

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-espresso

I'm writing UI Automation tests for an Android app using Espresso. The test will search for a barcode number and find the associated item, but this feature is only available to US users. The users market is identified by the device language (en_US, en_UK).

How can I write this test so that it won't fail every time I run the automated tests for the UK?

I accomplished this with XCTest for the iOS app by creating a method that checks the devices current language.

```
class MarketChecker: XCTestCase {

    func isUSLocale() -> Bool {
        return Locale.current.identifier == "en_US"
    }

    func isGBLocale() -> Bool {
        return Locale.current.identifier == "en_GB"
    }
}
```

The method is then called at the start of the test:

```
if isUSLocale() {
    <US specific test>
}
```

This allows me to run the same test suite without having failures caused by our apps regional differences.

Unfortunately (for me) Espresso does not like `if` statements so I'm not sure how to implement this for the Android app. Any insights would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: @dazza5000 The example code is in Swift. 
I'm trying to do the same thing I did in the example code but in Java with the Espresso framework. Espresso allows `try/catch` but I don't believe that is a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. This is useful if your app is in multiple markets controlled by the device language.

```
public static String deviceLocale() {
    return Locale.getDefault().getCountry();
}

public static boolean isGBLocale() {
    return deviceLocale().equals("GB");
}

public static boolean isAULocale() {
    return deviceLocale().equals("AU");
}

public static boolean isUSLocale() {
    return deviceLocale().equals("US");
}
```

This can be used to validate market specific differences or skip tests that would otherwise fail in that market.

```
if (isUSLocale()) {
    // US test
}
```